# Ways to apply dynamic style to same user control in different silverlight application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styles

I have created a user control in silver-light.

I
 will use this control in two different applications.

Each application has its own styling rules.

I want user control to adopt styling defined in the respective application.

One approach I found is

**1) Define two separate styling template of same key in the App.xaml of both application.**

**2) Use static resource binding to bind styling to the control.**

Is there other approach to do the same.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the style does not change within a single application I would define a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="MyUserControl />
```

If it changes per situation/view, apply a resource key and set the style per instance of the control.